# Run Kubernetes custom scheduler periodically

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

I've customized the kubernetes' scheduler using Scheduling framework described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/) which works fine every time a new pod is going to be created.
What i want additionally is to run the scheduler periodically on every pod. The purpose is to offload the pods to another node if needed.

How can i do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/scheduling/nodes-custom-scheduler.html)?

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez This post only mentions creating a custom scheduler. What i'm looking for is running this custom scheduler periodically(i.e. every minute) to offload pods(if necessary) to new nodes.